# Writing Typescript definitions for ES6 mixins

Tags: typescript, mixins

I am writing a Javascript UI library. Consider the following Javascript:

```
class Image {
  constructor() {
    this.isImage = true;
  }
}

class Text {
  constructor() {
    this.isText = true;
  }
}

const ButtonMixin = Superclass => (
  class Button extends Superclass {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.isButton = true;
    }
  }
);
```

I am trying to write a d.ts Typescript definition file for these classes and the button mixin.

Here is my attempt. How do I declare the ButtonMixin function?

```
declare class Image {
  isImage: boolean;
}

declare class Text {
  isText: boolean;
}

// This represents the inner class generated by ButtonMixin. It cannot be instantiated by itself, but should be usable as a type, such as a function parameter.
declare abstract class Button {
  isButton: boolean;
}

// How do I declare the mixin function? This is my naive attempt, but it does not produce the correct intellisense in WebStorm and VSCode, and I assume it's simply not correct. Note that the return type should be a class/constructor, not an instance.
declare function ButtonMixin<T>(baseClass: T): Button & T;
```

Consumers of my library should be able to do things like this:

```
// The consumer of my library should be able to declare objects like this.
const imageButton = new (ButtonMixin(Image));
imageButton. // The intellisense here should show two properties: isButton and isImage.

// Or, they should be able to use the mixin to create their own classes like this.
class TextButton extends ButtonMixin(Text) {
  constructor() {
    this.isTextButton = true;
  }
}
const textButton = new TextButton();
textButton. // The intellisense here should show three properties: isButton, isText, and isTextButton.
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm aware of that webpage, but my question is different in that I am writing a definition file and my inner class is declared separately. If I were to use this pattern and say `function ButtonMixin<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase)`, I still don't know what return type to use.

Comment: Try `declare function ButtonMixin<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(Superclass: T): new (...args: ConstructorParameters<T>) => T & { isButton: true }`. Note that your inner class in the mixim *must* take a single rest parameter of type `any[]` (and should call the superclass constructor with it).

Comment: Does [this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=142#code/MYewdgzgLgBAQgVylcBZAlgD3WGBeGAHgBUYBTTKMsAEwhjDIHcYAKAOk4EMAnAcwgAuGFzABPANoBdAJT4AfCPHzWAZQQAHMj2AAbLhCExiM4YxYdu-IwGFw0HgmAoeABV5cAtmSo8IJeTk8RVIAMhgAbxh0CERkcGEoRzIYAF8FNgAoGBg9A3o4lFwKKlp6dS0dfUNI7Jzc+ySnF0t2XgFhUUlZWvr6iE1tVhkAbky6vqgACxj2GMLwfBgmsjG+1LqN0cygA) work for you? If so I'll write it up as an answer. If not what am I missing?

Comment: Hey Jared, I just posted what I think is the correct answer. Your suggestion isn't what I'm looking for because the Button class remains internal to the mixin declaration. I want a separate definition for the Button class that can be exported and used externally as a type (see my comments in the original post). Thanks for your suggestion though! Revisiting the Typescript link you posted helped me build my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you to write in Typescript and let the compiler do the typings for you

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSC2YDmBTAjNA3gWAFDQOgCcUwATAewDsQBPaASwgWRQC5oAXIgVxWgC8XXijwBfPHlCQYAFRQAPThhz5CJctTqMI8pR259BwvuMm4GVTiiIAzMMH4AhHp07UVeQsVKUa9Jhc3agMRM1xOWgAHfgBhaghDYHciAB5ZY0wxAD5jKhQAd2gACgA6crAiJAgOMCpaAG0AXQBKQVzZAG5zWx4qZIZqaCD3KgBZBgVLVIBlHhiiaShoRWsqMhh4qkTeZIoibOKvQgh5myWa6DmFi7w21W8L4ddRian8shWlFHWYU5vwMsGPAoiAUPAfpwYCMPFhjt4CBo-NpAi8QiZ+EJDKI1AQJLifJweEQqM9guNJpYUJ9IFczotATAAGTQLY7Hh7NIwqhobLdXD4vAAeiF0FkAAt+MAEjwIURoBRbNB4PQQAwAEZESr0CDiig8ECfdX8MDqsFcCjQMgoaQkBXqgBWNqh0DVAGt+JxxUxSlIEpxGIhUNy8oUSty3pZiixUGgWi1+cDWNzStARWLJYwrCgQGqID989BJXbdfrDdBS0VOAVLVEiBQFpwGChLqjydA6p8mDGUL7cMLRQB5IgAGi4kp1eoNRpNZs9lp4ha9-HglNJ7mgwA01nHKAY8ooBVJFxbroYHvHPqkjLFqxDqx+GzJrzXxT0ynu8J07+5HHVFAoME6i-aVtiSFJik-AlvH+GxIK-bwvR9JgfzRUksREflvHxfFQMSLg7zQ0MilQ8lIP5awlBTNNRQlfhLGsXMmALfhi34UtpwrPUq3FEh+DrBsbCbFsODbUYxxQ1Yx07b9CPJUogA), js/d.ts are on right

```
// my code
class Image1 {
    readonly isImage: true = true
}

class Text1 {
    readonly isText: true = true
}

interface Button1 {
    readonly isButton: true
}
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function ButtonMixin<Superclass extends Constructor>(
    superclass: Superclass
) {
    class ButtonMixined extends superclass implements Button1 {
        readonly isButton: true = true
    }
    return ButtonMixined as Superclass & Constructor<Button1>;
}
```

---

```
// generated definitions
declare class Image1 {
    readonly isImage: true;
}
declare class Text1 {
    readonly isText: true;
}
interface Button1 {
    readonly isButton: true;
}
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
declare function ButtonMixin<Superclass extends Constructor>(superclass: Superclass): Superclass & Constructor<Button1>;
```

```
// generates ES2017 code
"use strict";
class Image1 {
    constructor() {
        this.isImage = true;
    }
}
class Text1 {
    constructor() {
        this.isText = true;
    }
}
function ButtonMixin(superclass) {
    class ButtonMixined extends superclass {
        constructor() {
            super(...arguments);
            this.isButton = true;
        }
    }
    return ButtonMixined;
}
```

---

Also note that you CAN'T make `Image` and `Text` globals in TS as they are DOM `<img>` and `#text` node classes (you may make them in a module)

Comment: Hey @DImava, thanks for the suggestions! Similar to my reply to @JaredSmith under the original question, this solution keeps the Button class scoped and internal to the mixin declaration. I want the Button class to be exportable and usable externally. For example, I want someone to be able to write: `function myFunc(button: Button)`. I posted an answer. Let me know if you have any feedback.

Comment: @TarczaBoga Button shouldn't be a "class" as it's not instantianable, e.g. user can write `class X extends Button` and that'll be *runtime* error

Comment: that is a great point about the abstract class. It can't be instantiated, but it can be extended, which isn't valid. However, an interface doesn't work for me because I want to have protected fields/methods documented in case the consumer of the library uses the mixin to create their own class. So, I guess I need to find a way to 'seal' the class also. It looks like I might be able to do this with a private constructor.

Comment: @TarczaBoga then yes, a declared class with private fields should work fine

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimentation, I believe I found what I'm looking for:

```
declare class Image {
  isImage: boolean;
}

declare class Text {
  isText: boolean;
}

// This represents the inner class generated by ButtonMixin. It cannot be instantiated by itself, but should be usable as a type, such as a function parameter.
declare abstract class Button {
  isButton: boolean;
}

// The correct mixin definition:
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => {};
declare function ButtonMixin<TBase extends Constructor>(baseClass: TBase): {new(...args: any[]): Button} & TBase;
```

Notice that with this solution, Button remains a separate definition as an abstract class. Now, it can be exported and used as a type, such as `function myFunc(button: Button)`. This is very important for my project, because these classes are very complex in my real code. I think this was the pain point that I didn't really see in other questions / examples.